# If I have a IRibbonUI object stored can I use it to add controls to the ribbon using VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba, ribbon

Given that I have stored the IRibbonUI object onLoad, can I use that to modify the CustomUI.xml in my stub .xlam ribbon? If not, can it be used to add tabs, controls, etc. via VBA code?

Answer (score 0):

The *IRibbonUI* object can only invalidate, i.e. reset the caches, on already defined controls and switch tabs on the ribbon.  However, you can use the invalidation to trigger callbacks which show/hide already-defined controls by using the *getVisible* property, for example see this answer:
[Hide individual custom ribbon buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18043318/hide-individual-custom-ribbon-buttons).
Or change their images as per:
[Excel Ribbon Dropdown background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37784586/excel-ribbon-dropdown-background-color).

The Ribbon XML is immutable for the life of the related COM add-in.  If you want to specify a completely new Ribbon XML, you need another master/controller addin to disconnect and re-connect the COM addin which declared the Ribbon.  This is a bit more complicated, so hopefully you can achieve what you need with the *getVisible* functionality.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. I will look for other methods to accomplish my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for that confirmation. I saw that this can be done in MS Project but, sadly, not in Excel.

All of the other items you mentioned regarding callbacks are in place and working well. Hide/show, changing labels, etc. but always on pre-defined controls.